# System.ENUM has no supported translation to SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to do a group by in LINQ to SQL but I want to base the grouping on the text description of my ENUM items.

```
        var qry = from s in _db.Complaints 
                  where s.Site.SiteDescription.Contains(searchTextSite)
                    && (s.Raised >= startDate && s.Raised <= endDate)
                  group s by s.ComplaintNatureTypeId.ToDescription()
                      into grp
                      select new
                      {
                          Site = grp.Key,
                          Count = grp.Count()
                      };
```

I'm thinking this must be supported since its very fundamental and think i'm missing something simple.

Anyone any ideas on how i'm getting runtime error & how to remedy this

thanks in advance

Comment: which one is enumeration in this query

Answer (score 1):

Linq to Sql is translated to Sql query so everything must be convertable to query. You can not group items by something that is only in your code. If u want to group by enum you can use ints its unique as your string enums.